# Trying to build an sql query using Sqlkata with multiple conditions

Tags: sqlkata

I am trying to achieve the below query by using the SQLKata. Was able to partially achieve with the code below and still struck creating the Or grouping in the expected query below(highlighted in bold).

**Expected Query**
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON (A.C1 = B.BC1 AND A.C2 = B.BC2 AND A.C3 = B.BC3) **OR (A.C5 = B.BC5 AND A.C6 = C.BC6)**
WHERE A.BATCH = 1

There is a configuration table where we store our config.
My Configuration is as below

| field | matching_field | matching_table | new_or_group? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | BC1 | B | No |
| C2 | BC2 | B | No |
| C3 | BC3 | B | No |
| C5 | BC5 | B | Yes |
| C6 | BC6 | B | No |

The primary table is "A" and which then joins with the matching table "B" on the above field conditions

Below is the code I did.

```
   query.Join(matching_table, q =>
        {
            bool bReset = false;
            foreach (TBLConfiguration internalField in fields)
            {
                if (bReset == false)
                {
                    if (internalField.field == null)
                    {
                        q.WhereNull(internalField.matching_field);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        q.On(internalField.matching_field, 
                      internalField.field, "=");
                    }
                }


                 if (bReset == true)
                 {
                    if (internalField.field == null)
                    {
                       //This is where i am trying to do the start 
                       "Or" condition for the join (second group)
                       q.OrWhereNull(internalField.matching_field);
                    }
                    
                    bReset = false;
                }

                if (internalField.new_or_group? == "yes")
                {
                    bReset = true;
                }

            }

            return q;
        });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, try to post the configuration table data, with the expected SQL query

Comment: I updated the my question to provide some more clarity. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: @amd, this is a very nice library and I am just struck with doing the above. Any help is highly appreciated.